# Is there a way to make ServiceStack.Redis use JSON.NET instead of ServiceStack.Text?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, redis, servicestack

Is there a way to make ServiceStack.Redis use JSON.NET instead of ServiceStack.Text?

The reason I am asking is because of a specific case where integers are converted to strings in ServiceStack.Text but not in JSON.NET

This is a huge deal when sending data over the wire to the web.

In our specific case, JSON.NET stores data as
'Offset': 0
and ServiceStack.Text stores data as
'Offset' : '0'

Why is this very bad? In javascript, 29 + 0 = 29 but 29 + '0' = '290'. This means array[29 + offset] can yield strange results with ServiceStack.Text

I know this is a specific use case, but it'll be a lot easier to use JSON.NET (which behaves as expected) instead of ServiceStack.Text (which is 3 times faster but does not behave as expected).

Comment: This is very interesting...are you serializing from C# objects to redis?  This seems to be a misunderstanding of your native types during serialization to Redis.

Comment: I'm relying on ServiceStack.Redis to serialize the objects, which relies on ServiceStack.Text to do the actual conversion.

ServiceStack.Text does not behave as desired, so I was wondering if I could just tell ServiceStack to use the proven JSON.NET (which is one of the most popular nuget packages out there for a reason)

Comment: Even if this bug is fixed in the servicestack source code, the fact it exists in the first place gives me enough of a pause not to trust servicestack.text over json.net at all.

Comment: The actual use case is this: C# dictionary (string keys, object values) gets converted to JSON.

ServiceStack.Text stores integers as strings. JSON.NET stores integers as integers.

Comment: That's probably your issue.  By using the object values ServiceStack text is making an assumption.  Is there any way you can cast to proper type right before serialization?

Comment: An integer is a primitive type that is stored in the dictionary. I am storing the dictonary. ServiceStack.Text is not handling this correctly and JSON.NET is. I'd have to modify the source code of ServiceStack.text to fix this issue, get it approved, and get the latest distro. Aside form the time issue there's the trust issue.

Comment: I am calling a method in servicestack.redis to seralize the dicontary. Servicestack.redis is third party code. The third party code is calling other third party code (servicestack.text) which is bugged. I want it to call third party code that is not bugged (JSON.NET)

Answer (score 2):

It does not store numbers as text, Actual behavior in ServiceStack.Text:

```
public class HasOffset
{
    public int Offset { get; set; }
}

var dto = new HasOffset { Offset = 1 };
string json = dto.ToJson();
json.Print(); //prints {"Offset":1}

var fromJson = json.FromJson<HasOffset>();
Assert.That(fromJson.Offset, Is.EqualTo(1));
```

If you're trying to deserialize it using [JsonObject](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonObject.cs#L67) it gets parsed into a `Dictionary<string,string>` Dictionary it gets coerced to a string. Likewise if you're trying to store it into a `object` the serializer doesn't know what type it should convert it to so it leaves it as a string.

Comment: I did not expect to get an answer from mythz himself! The specific use case I have is a dictionary of objects keyed by string. If one of the items in that dictionary is an int it gets stored as a string. Since it's you who spent the time to reply, I'll respect that and put up a code sample of where this happens (though it may take a day or two). It was this specific use case that caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can only switch between ServiceStack's JsonSerializer and the built-in JsonDataContractSerializer which you can do by adding this to the AppHost.Configure section:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
    UseBclJsonSerializers = true
});
```

Please see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/servicestack/xN7wmcCtr88/discussion) thread for the reference to the above information.

It would appear that they simply don't support an out-of-box configurable option for different serializers.